# Access Json data in a task in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

Hi i am triggering a dag with a dag id dag_1 using airflow's REST api and python requests module and in this request I want to send the json data (dic) too. this is how i and sending

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

dic = {
    "flag": "flag",
    "files": "files",
    "upload_path": "config.UPLOAD_FOLDER",
    "tmp_path": "config.TMP_FOLDER",
    "dataset_id": "dataset_id",
    "dicom_meta_data": "dicom_meta_data",
    "user_id": "request.user.id",
    "protocol": "http if request.is_secure() else http",
    "current_site": "request.get_host()",
    "deidentify": "deidentify",
    "email": "request.user.email",
}
json_object = json.dumps(dic)
data = {
    "conf": {},
    "dag_run_id": "trigger_16",
    "logical_date": "2022-08-29T11:33:49.726Z",
}
headers={
    'Content-type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json'
}
json_payload = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/dag_1/dagRuns", auth=HTTPBasicAuth("airflow", "airflow"), data=json_payload, headers=headers, json=json_object)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

and its working fine. but now i want to access this json in my first task in airflow which i am not able to do. Can anyone help me in this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the dict to your run in order to access it by `dag_run.conf` or `params`, you should add it to your run data:

```py
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

dic = {
    "flag": "flag",
    "files": "files",
    "upload_path": "config.UPLOAD_FOLDER",
    "tmp_path": "config.TMP_FOLDER",
    "dataset_id": "dataset_id",
    "dicom_meta_data": "dicom_meta_data",
    "user_id": "request.user.id",
    "protocol": "http if request.is_secure() else http",
    "current_site": "request.get_host()",
    "deidentify": "deidentify",
    "email": "request.user.email",
}
data = {
    "conf": dic,
    "dag_run_id": "trigger_16",
    "logical_date": "2022-08-29T11:33:49.726Z",
}
headers={
    'Content-type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json'
}
json_payload = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/dag_1/dagRuns", auth=HTTPBasicAuth("airflow", "airflow"), json=json_payload, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```